# Good ways to implement multi sizes for thumbnails?

Tags: php, thumbnails

Thanks for jumping by!

I'm building a PHP script to manage employees, and I would like to get your help in deciding which good way do you use to implement multiple size for profile picture thumbnail.

The sizes may change (would like to keep it dynamic), thus, I can't set a specific column name for each thumbnail size.

I assume there are few options:

1. I can create a database table for each profile picture, there I will save the thumbnail path and "bind" to the user id with a foreign key, then I will be able to get all profile pictures and sort them based on my needs.
2. I can generate a thumbmail and save its path in the "users" table in a special column called "thumb_path" or something similar - in the same way I can store instead json of the profile picture paths (while the key represent the thumbnail size).

But both seems to be a bit wierd for me, and I can't clearly thing about another way to implement in efficiently.

Will be happy to get your kind help!
Marco.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create one table for the thumbnails, with a reference to the user_id, the thumb path and the info about the size. You can have multiple rows for a user. 
Hope this will help you.